# MSQL select one of each

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

i have a table like this...

```
username     action   time
user1        login    00.00.00
user1        logout   01.00.00
user2        login    02.00.00
```

i want to select last action of each username on 02.00.00 so it must be like this..

```
user1 logout
user2 login
```

I have tried this but looks like doesnt complete yet.

```
select (distinct username), action from log where date(time) <= '02.00.00'
```

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the max of time for each user in subquery and inner join it with the main table like this:

```
select a.*
from log a
inner join (
    select username, max(time) time
    from log
    where time <= '02.00.00'
    group by username
) b on a.username = b.username
    and a.time = b.time;
```

One thing to note here is if there are multiple rows with same maximum time, the query will display all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Use Subquery

```
select username,action from log where time in( select max(time) from log group by username);
```

by using time period:

```
select username,action from log where time in( select max(time) from log group by username having time < '2.00.00');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 select * from (select * from log order by time desc) log group by username;
```

[check on sqlfiddel](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3d307)